# Create a python like list in c++

Tags: python, c++, list, translate

I have a python script that I have to translate in c++, and 80 % of my python script is based on lists.

I have a file that I read, and put the data of that file in a list :

```
//Code to translate in c++
bloc = [line]
for b in range(11):
    bloc.append(lines[i + 1])
    i += 1
```

I make my stuff with that data and then, I do it again until I read the whole file.

And finally I want to be able to get data of this list doing something like :

```
#Python script
var = bloc[0, 1, 2, 3 ...]
```

I'll respond to any questions you need more infos

Comment: just use `std::vector`

Comment: **Read**  [more about C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp), in particular a **good [C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) book**. The use some C++ [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). Provide some [MRE] in C++ in your question. StackOverflow is *not* a *do-my-homework* website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ container closest to a python `List` is a `std::vector`. However contrary to python a `std::vector` contains only one type of element. You have to declare what the vector will hold.
In your case it would be `std::string` (reading from a file).

So:

```
std::vector<std::string> cpp_list; // container for lines (stored as string )from the file
```

is equivalent to python `python_list = []`
should get you started.

With a `std::vector` you do not strictly need to allocated storage upfront but for performance reason it is better to do is if you know the required size in advance.

- if you use `cpp_list.reserve(something)` or do not do any memory allocation, you must push in the vector using `cpp_list.push_back(...)` which is similar to `pyhton_list.append(...)`
- If you allocate memory upfront eg: `std::vector<std::string> cpp_list(nb_lines)` 
  You must use indexing as in python eg `cpp_list[3] = something`

Comment: Can you show me a program that is like my python script ? I'm trying to do it but I have this error : Error: no matching member function for call to 'push_back'

Comment: Hello. Please share your code and we will start from there.

Comment: Regarding _"If you allocate memory upfront ... You **must use indexing** as in python"_, is that correct though? I've found `push_back` to work just fine after pre-allocating memory

Comment: Hello morganstark47. Allocating (eg resize) and pre allocating (reserve) are not the same in c++. If you call reserve then the vector internal index starts at 0. Element you push back indeed start at pos 0,then 1,... If you allocate for size N, internal index starts at N-1. You can still do push_back but elements will be added from position N-1